IVsWindowFrame CloseFrame not working as intended on .xaml files
I'm trying to build a Visual Studio 2022 extension that closes tabs based on certain conditions.
When I'm using VsWindowFrame.CloseFrame() on most file types, it works as intended (the tab just closes).
But when I'm calling the above function on .xaml files, the content of the file disappears, but the tab is still open.
After I close the .xaml file from my code, when I press "Close" or on the "X" button, the tab is still not closing, but "Close All Tabs" or "Close Document Tabs" commands do work.
this i how call close window
  foreach (IVsWindowFrame frame in frames)
  {
      var result =   frame.CloseFrame((uint)__FRAMECLOSE.FRAMECLOSE_PromptSave);    
      //just for tests      
      var closedResult = result == VSConstants.S_OK; //true
      frame.IsOnScreen(out int isOnScreen);
      var IsOnScreenResult = isOnScreen == VSConstants.S_OK; //true
      var isVisibleResult = frame.IsVisible() == VSConstants.S_OK; //false
      var hideResult = frame.Hide() == VSConstants.S_OK; //false 

  }

I get the same error code -2146232798 (could not find what it means via VSConstants)

Did  you seen that  the return is  S_OK. or an error code when it closes .xml files? It's better if you can share code snip to help us better understand your scenario and do further investigation.

@DouXu-MSFT added code snippet and more data

Hi @styx, i could not find what -2146232798 means via VSConstants too. I suggest you to click feedback on this page to ask MS product team how to find this error code via VSConstants.

I Manged to solve it by calling DTE2.ActiveDocument.Close()
foreach (IVsWindowFrame frame in frames)
{
    var CloseFrameResult =   frame.CloseFrame((uint)__FRAMECLOSE.FRAMECLOSE_PromptSave);
    frame.IsOnScreen(out int isOnScreen);  
    if(CloseFrameResult !=  VSConstants.S_OK || frame.IsVisilbe !=  VSConstants.S_OK || isOnScreen !=  VSConstants.S_OK) 
    {
       var dte = await ServiceProivder.GetGlobalServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
       if(dte?.ActiveDocumnet is { ActiveDocumnet : not null}
       {
           dte.ActiveDocumnet.Close()
       }
    }  

